# Real inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, composition, prototypal-inheritance

I tried to implement prototypical inheritance between two AngularJS services and one generic service, but this seems not enough to serve my needs.

I made `ChildService`, `SecondChildService` and `ParentService`.

- `ChildService` extends `ParentService` with prototypical inheritance
- `SecondChildService` extends `ParentService` with prototypical inheritance

`ParentService` has a method let's call it `logIt()` that logs property `it`

- `ChildService` implements its own version of `it`
- `SecondChildService` implements its own version of `it`

Now I consider `ParentService` as the "base class", and I have a method within `ParentService` that calls `logIt()`, that is `initialize()`. This is only implemented in `ParentService`

I need to run `ChildService.initialize()` and see that the `it` of `ChildService` gets logged.
The same thing with `SecondChildService`.

Instead the `ParentService` logs its own version of `it`. The reason I believe is that prototypical inheritance is a ***composition*** implementation ***rather than real inheritance***

**Can you please propose a workaround?**

---

***Edit:***

This is my parent service

```
angular.module('common').service('parentService', ParentService);
ParentService.$inject = [];

/* @ngInject */
function ParentService() {
  'use strict';
  var vm = this;
  vm.it = "parent";

  vm.initialize = function () {
    vm.logIt();
  };

  vm.logIt = function () {
    console.log(this.it);
  };
}
```

This is my child service

```
angular.module('common').service('childService', ChildService);
ChildService.$inject = ['parentService'];

/* @ngInject */
function ChildService(parentService) {
  'use strict';
  var vm = this;
  angular.extend(this, parentService);
  vm.it = "child";
}
```

And this is what I get in the log when I run `childService.initialize()`

```
parent
```

I am expecting to get `child` instead

Comment: It would be helpful if you include code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `angular.extend` does. In Javascript the prototype is set with [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) not with `angular.extend`. This is what `class B extends A` uses under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `ParentService`. I am using `vm.logIt`, while I should be using `this.logIt` in order to get the `it` from the child service scope. Contrary to standard inheritance, it seems that in prototypical inheritance the `logIt()` function exists twice, once in the `ParentService` and once in the `ChildService` (inherited from parent). With `this.logIt()` you can call it from the child and it actually gets the `it` from the child, while with `vm.logIt()` you call it from the parent where it gets the `it` from. It is a matter of scope.

This is the correct implementation of `ParentService`:

```
angular.module('common').service('parentService', ParentService);
ParentService.$inject = [];

/* @ngInject */
function ParentService() {
  'use strict';
  var vm = this;
  vm.it = "parent";

  vm.initialize = function () {
    this.logIt(); // <-- this changed
  };

  vm.logIt = function () {
    console.log(this.it);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem. Inheritance seems to work correctly in the following example:

```js
class Main {
    do_it() {
        console.log("Main do_it");
        this.it();
    }
    it() {
        console.log("Main it executed");
    }
}

class A extends Main {
    it() {
        console.log("A it executed");
    }
}

var a = new A;
a.do_it();
console.log("Done");
```

The `do_it` method that is defined in the `Main` class correctly calls the `it` method of the extended class which has overridden the `it` method of the parent class.